# use withContext once on twice. Both work, or

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I must execute http request (Retrofit 2) in background thread.

**approach #1:**

```
 suspend fun getTraidersList(): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)
            executeOperation { traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList() }
        }


  suspend private fun executeOperation(transportOperation: suspend () -> Response<*>): TransportResponse {
            try {
                val response: Response<*> = transportOperation()
                return onResponse(response)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                return onNetworkFailure(e)
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see the method `getTraidersList()` is start in background thread by `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. But in method `executeOperation` I'm not using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Nice. It's work fine.

**approach #2:**

Using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`  also in method  `executeOperation`

```
suspend fun getTraidersList(): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)
            executeOperation { traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList() }
}

 suspend private fun executeOperation(transportOperation: suspend () -> Response<*>): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response: Response<*> = transportOperation()
                onResponse(response)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onNetworkFailure(e)
            }
}
```

Both approaches work.
But which approach is correct? Maybe, both approaches are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to reuse the `executeOperation` method anywhere else it's okay to put into another thread but for now, in your case, it's not needed.

This can also work in case you want to reuse the `executeOperation` method.

```
suspend fun getTraidersList(): TransportResponse {
            val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)
            executeOperation { traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList() }
}

 suspend private fun executeOperation(transportOperation: suspend () -> Response<*>): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response: Response<*> = transportOperation()
                onResponse(response)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onNetworkFailure(e)
            }
}
```